# Wireless drivers failing to build when make command is run

Tags: wireless, drivers, compiling

I'll have to start by saying I'm new to ubuntu, and linux in general. 
I have set up a dual boot on my pc with windows and linux.
Due to positioning in my house, I'm unable to get ethernet access, so I use an external wireless adapter that functions fine in windows. There ARE linux drivers, which I have downloaded on the system.
So far, I've entered:

```
cd /usr/src/8812au-4.2.2
make
```

However, this fails to build. It returns with this:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/build M-/usr/src/8812au-4.2.2 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
```

From here, I'm not entirely sure where to go. If I try to continue, it finds that it doesn't build the 8812au.ko that I need.

Are there any ideas about what I could do from here?

EDIT:
I downloaded the drivers from here:
https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
The drivers DO have instructions on using dkms, which also failed to work properly. Would you like to see what is returned when I try to install it through that?

Comment: Please edit to add the URL of where you found this code.  The folder name seems to indicate it is made to support DKMS

Comment: I... don't see any errors here.  Is there any other output from `make` here, or did you paste the complete output?

Comment: DKMS is probably not installed.

Comment: @Pilot6  Makefile is messed up, I used this [one](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/blob/master/Makefile) with that code and it build the modules.  Looking at the diff now

Comment: @Jeremy31 Why not just use the official package?

Comment: I took the question as being more why it doesn't work, wasn't aware of a package.  Is this something that is going to be in tree?

Comment: Well, it is a good question why it is not in tree. ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This driver is included in Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04.
It can be also installed to Ubuntu 14.04.4 with 4.2 kernels (see the offline guide).

Most likely it will install on the previous kernels, but that is not guaranteed.

It can be installed for `wily` or `xenial` by

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

You need to uninstall all other drivers for this adapter first.

You can install this driver offline this way:

1. Download these files to your Home directory

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8812au/rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu1_all.deb

2. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtl8812au-dkms*.deb
   ```

Comment: Will this function without access to internet on the device? I cannot use ethernet with my positioning.

Comment: I will add directions on how to install offline. What is the ubuntu version?

Comment: My version of Ubuntu is 14.04.4 64 bit

Comment: You, my friend, have solved my problem! I really appreciate it!